# How to make a pagebreak item submit instead of continue?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Trying to get a section in my form to submit instead of continue. So the only way I found is to add

```
FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT
```

to each choice?? But when I do that:

```
mat_q = form.addCheckboxItem();
mat_ch = [];
for(....){mat_ch.push(mat_q.createChoice(lines[dd].join(), FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT))}
mat_q.setChoices(mat_ch)
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot find method createChoice(string,PageNavigationType)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it eventually, the solution is stupid as hell.
Basically when you set a pagebreak you can also set a gotopage for the page before?? So I just settup a trigger that after a pagebreak create that I want to submit after I switch it on and after every pagebreak create I put an if(switch) to set that pagebreak gotopage.

Weird that all this is order based rather than assignment based